# Alterar uma busca de classe no jQuery, para uma busca de palavra

Tags: javascript, jquery

Desculpem se não fui claro na minha pergunta. Estou iniciando com *JS* e *jQuery* e minha dúvida é a seguinte: no código abaixo, exite alguma forma de ao invés de procurar por classes, procurar por palavras?

```
when(function() {
    return jQuery != undefined && jQuery('.classe1, .classe2').length;
})
```

Comment: O que você quer dizer exatamente por buscar por palavras? O jQuery utilizar seletores CSS, portanto você pode usar qualquer regra de seletor CSS para fazer sua busca. Referência de seletores CSS: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: Cara, não sei me expressar muito bem nessa situação, mas eu preciso mesmo da seleção por palavras. No caso, se existir, colocar de alguma forma palavras no lugar de '.classe1, .classe2'

realente nem sei se isso é possível, simplesmente digitando as palavras não deu certo, mas estou em busca de outra forma.

Comment: Tente descrever melhor o que você quer fazer, quem sabe a solução pode ser diferente da que você está tentando.

Comment: tenho um html que vai procurar essas classes, e aparecer após elas, mas queria fazer isso por palavras

sei que minha explicação é confusa, foi mal mesmo pessoal

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Para fazer uma busca por string em atributo, você pode usar o seletor Atributo = Valor.

Documentação: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attribute_value.asp

Exemplo:

```js
var texto1 = $('[class*="teste1"]').text();
var texto2 = $('[class*="teste5"]').text();
var texto3 = $('[class*="teste9"]').text();

$('#seletor-1').html(texto1);
$('#seletor-2').html(texto2);
$('#seletor-3').html(texto3);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="teste1 teste2 teste3">Lorem ipsum sit dolor ommet 1</p>
<p class="teste4 teste5 teste6">Lorem ipsum sit dolor ommet 2</p>
<p class="teste7 teste8 teste9">Lorem ipsum sit dolor ommet 3</p>

<hr>

<p id="seletor-1"></p>
<p id="seletor-2"></p>
<p id="seletor-3"></p>
```

No caso deste exemplo, foi utilizado [class*="PALAVRA"], onde "class" é o atributo da tag (poderia ser qualquer outro atributo), "*=" é um operador que indica "contenha" e "PALAVRA" é a string a ser procurada.